# How do I use Google Cloud Vision API to return the image with the highest confidence for a particular label?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have a list of external URLs (.jpg or .png images) and want to send those  as requests to the Google Cloud Vision API for label detection. I want the image with the highest confidence for a particular label(s) returned first. Basically I would like to sort images in descending order of confidence for a label (such as car).

So far I've figured out how to annotate images stored locally but am trying to figure out how I can feed it a list of external image URLs and sort them by confidence for 'car'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a request with several image, if you save it in Google Cloud Storage for example. But you have to be aware on total size of 8Mb per request.

Then you can save the metadata locally and order it as you want. Google Vision API doesn't give to you the functionality that you want natively.

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/best-practices

Comment: Thanks - so I guess my next step would be to find a way to save the returned tags as metadata and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the Python Google Vision SDK allows you to send external URLs, per their documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels#detecting_labels_in_a_remote_image.